# Are there any pigments which can be altered via the use of electricty?

Tags: electricity, visible-light

I was looking at alternative visual output methods for computer, phone and the like and was wondering, are there pigments, Red, Green and Blue preferably, that can have their intensity/opacity modified by the use of electricty? Are such pigments even feasable? Would they be more energy efficient than current TFT display technology?

Comment: That's what electronic paper displays do: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper. A simple (albeit practically useless) chemical display could use pH dependent dyes in an electrolytic cell.

Comment: Why aren't such technologies more common?

Comment: Currently they are rather limited in their resolution and color reproduction. Resolution can be improved, color reproduction, on the other hand, runs into a fundamental problem. A reflective pigment can only reflect the colors of light shining on it. If you look at a reflective color display in red light, only the red component will show significant variation on intensity, the green and blue layers will completely disappear. Displays that generate their own light do not suffer from this limitation and can reproduce colors correctly for any illumination.